# Searching through Arraylist of Arraylist

Tags: java, search, arraylist, data-structures

I'm trying this for a game 
I have multiple aircrafts and cells representing the sky! 
one cell can have multiple objects (aircrafts) and cell has x,y,z
how to get(x,y,z) the oldest element in a certain cell? 
I used ArrayList of ArrayList to store multiple elements in one cell
and now I need to search through the cells! whats the best approach to doing that?

Here is my sample code

```
ArrayList <Integer> coord1 = new ArrayList ();
    coord1.add(1);
    coord1.add(1);
    coord1.add(1);

    ArrayList <Integer> coord2 = new ArrayList ();
    coord2.add(3);
    coord2.add(3);
    coord2.add(3);


    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    list1.add("aircraft1");
    list1.add("aircraft2");

    ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
    list2.add("aircraft3");
    list2.add("aircraft4");


ArrayList<ArrayList> cell1 = new ArrayList();
cell1.add(coord1);
cell1.add(list1);


ArrayList<ArrayList> cell2 = new ArrayList();
cell2.add(coord2);
cell2.add(list2);


// How to search through! Get aircraft in a certain position

}

public static void getAircrafts (int x, int y ,int z) {


    }

public void iterator (ArrayList list) {
    Iterator<ArrayList> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());    

}
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please fix the code formatting and make sure the number of `{` is equal to `}`.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` will work for you if your key is the location of the aircraft. If you have multiple threads operating upon the `Map`, then you'll need to synchronize access.

If you need to access aircraft via multiple keys (i.e., by name or by location), then you'll want to store aircraft in multiple `HashMap` structures.

EDIT 1

If a location can have multiple aircraft, then a key's value must be a list of some kind (perhaps an `ArrayList`). If a location may never have multiple aircraft, then the key's value can be the aircraft.

Comment: Do I need to modify the hashmap for collision ? as the cell "key" may have more than 1 airplane